# Left Join using Linq with Lambda Expressions returning the Left table

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, left-join

i try to make a Lambda expression to get every Case that is in a folder from a specific Application. 
I have 2 tables:

table 1: Cases

```
CaseId | FolderId | CaseContent
0        1          "blap"
1        2          "blop"
2        1          "blup"
3        3          "blip"
```

table2: Folders

```
FolderId | ApplicationId
0          1
1          1
2          1
3          2
```

I want to return every case thats in a folder with ApplicationId 1.

result:

```
  CaseId | FolderId | CaseContent
  0        1          "blap"
  1        2          "blop"
  2        1          "blup"
```

I found a nice example of a Join expression here: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/inner-join-using-linq-with-lambda/

The reason why i can't use this is because it returns content from both tables

```
 var query = objEntities.Employee.Join(objEntities.Department, r => r.EmpId, p => p.EmpId, (r,p) => new{r.FirstName, r.LastName, p.DepartmentName});
```

so instead of

```
 (r,p) => new{r.FirstName, r.LastName, p.DepartmentName}
```

i want it to return the entire 'r' and nothing of 'p'.

i tryed something in the lines of

```
IQueryable<Case> cases = Cases.Join(Folders, f => f.Folder.folderId, c => c.folderId, (c) => c);
```

Needles to say it doesn't work. :(

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well theres several ways you could do this.

But to get your join expression correct you'd want

```
IQueryable<Case> cases                                 //line:#1
= Cases.Join(Folders.Where(f => f.ApplicationId == 1), //line:#2
             c => c.folderId,                          //line:#3
             f => f.folderId,                          //line:#4
             (f,c) => c);                              //line:#5
```

Explanation:

.Join takes four parameters. (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534644%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for a full description)

- 1st is the collection that you are joining 2 (as on line 2 above). You only want the subset of folders that has ApplicationId equal to 1, hence the `.Where(f => f.ApplicationId == 1)`
- 2nd is an expression that identifies the key that you are joining on in the outer collection (Cases) (as on line 3 above)
- 3rd is an expression that identifies the key that you are joining on in the inner collection (Folders) (as on line 4 above)
- 4th is an expression that selects the results from the 2 joined collections. The left hand side of this expression needs to take 2 parameters that represent the 2 sides of the join, and the right hand side can be some combination of these. (as on line 5 above)

I often prefer using a linq expression though like:

```
var query = from c in Cases
            join f in Folders on c.FolderId equals f.FolderId
            where f.ApplicationId == 1
            select c;
```

Think that's a bit more readable!

Comment: no worries! If this answers your question, then please mark it as an answer.